# Mismatch of manual computation of a evaluation metrics with Sklearn functions

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, precision-recall

I wanted to compare the manual computations of the precision and recall with scikit-learn functions. However,  `recall_score()` and `precision_score()` of  scikit-learn functions gave me different results. Not sure why! Could you please give me some advice why I am getting different results? Thanks!

My confusion matrix:

[image]

```
tp, fn, fp, tn = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_test_pred).ravel()
print('Outcome values : \n', tp, fn, fp, tn)
```

```
Outcome values : 
 3636933 34156 127 151
```

```
FDR=tp/(tp+fn) # TPR/Recall/Sensitivity
print('Recall: %.3f' % FDR)
```

```
Recall: 0.991
```

```
precision=tp/(tp + fp)
print('Precision: %.3f' % precision)
```

```
Precision: 1.000
```

```
precision = precision_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
print('Precision: %f' % precision)
recall = recall_score(y_test, y_test_pred)
print('Recall: %f' % recall)
```

```
Precision: 0.004401
Recall: 0.543165
```

Comment: Please provide sample data (minimum reproducible example). When I tried with an example, the values match whether calculated manually or by using sklearn functions.

Comment: @SoniaSamipillai I have massive dataset. I have added the confusion matrix for ur convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be (check return value's ordering):

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_test_pred).ravel()
```

Please refer: [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)